# How to hide a particular value from a filter in Spotfire?

Tags: visualization, spotfire, tibco

I am looking to hide a value in the filter panel in Spotfire, is there a easy way to do this ?

Say I have the following values in a filter
value1
value2 
value3

I would like my filter to display only value1 and value2. I need to hide the value3. Is this possible in Spotfire ? Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Deepthi

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this and keep the filter in the filter panel is to create a calculated column with only the values you want represented, and then use this column in the filter panel. Note, there will be a `NULL` or `EMPTY` value for all values not meeting your condition, so you'll always have 1 extra value (but not `n` extra values)